Android Bitcoin wallet that let import wallet.dat file from Bitcoin core
I received bitcoins from a bankruptcy but in real life following a trial, my computer no longer have ram (manufacturer refused lifetime warrenty) and I have only about 30€ left.
So I only have my android phone left. I can’t use the wallet.dat file I registered several month ago since I only have a 512Mb ram laptop (maximum supportted by the motherboard).
Is there any Android Bitcoin wallet that can import wallet.dat files from Bitcoin core ?

The computer which no longer have ram only support ecc modules that are at least 32Gb large.
